I am trying to fit a logistic sigmoid function to data. The data in the y-axis is reversed to show length change over x-axis progression. T
I have many datasets which start at a higher y-axis value, then decrease. This happens in traditional S-curve fashion, so it actually looks like a reverse sigmoid. I successfully flipped the y-data so that the maximum value is at the bottom in the y-axis, and it decreases upward. So, data plots fine. The curve now looks like a standard sigmoid.
The Big Issue:
I cannot fit the sigmoid to it. I have done everything I can think of for a few days.
The best result I have is in the attached image.
I have many fits that just look incomplete and nowhere close to what a sigmoid fit should be.
Example of best result it plots: (https://i.sstatic.net/NPVry.png)
The code I have:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# 1. Data set: 
x_data = np.array([130, 125, 120, 115, 110, 105, 100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 45, 40,     
35, 30, 25])
y_data = np.array([81, 81, 80.5, 79, 77.5, 76, 74.5, 71.5, 68.5, 67, 64, 59.5, 55, 48.5, 44, 42.5, 42,     
41.5, 41.5, 41, 41, 41])

# 2. Reverse the y-values: 
y_data_reversed = np.flip(y_data)
y_range = np.linspace(41, 61.75, 81)

# 3. Sigmoid function defined: 
def sigmoid(x, U, k, a, b): 
    b = 81 #-the maxmimum y_data value. 
    return (U / (1 + np.exp(-k * (x - 77.5))))**a + b

p0 = [np.max(y_data), np.median(x_data), 1, np.min(y_data)] #-as an initial guess for the fit     
calculation. 
popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_data, p0, maxfev = 10000) #method = 'lm')

# 4. Sigmoid fit to data: 
x_fit = np.linspace(25, 77.5, 130) #-min(x_data), np.median(x_data), max(x_data)). 
y_fit = sigmoid(x_fit, *popt) 

# 5. Plot data and sigmoid fit:
plt.plot(x_data, y_data_reversed, marker='o', linestyle='', color='b', label='Data')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, color='r', label='Sigmoid Fit')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)')
plt.ylabel('Length (mm)')
plt.title('Sigmoid Fit for Contraction Data')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()  # ...Invert y-axis to start with highest value at the top
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show() 


B.t.w. you can simply paste an image into the editor and it will appear inline in your post.  No need to host it somewhere via a link.

Why do you only plot the solution between 25 <= x <= 77.5 and not over the full data range?  Did you mean x_fit = np.linspace(25, 130, 101)?

The argument b to the sigmoid function is unused because it is set to a new value inside the function.  Is this intentional?

You are plotting the y_data_reversed data but fitting to the unflipped y_data.  If you don't plot the same data you fitted the curve to, it will never look like a good fit.

In general, making an exponent a decision-variable, as in the a argument in your sigmoid function, is dangerous because you can easily cause numerical over/underflow or even generate complex numbers depending on what values the optimizer chooses for the parameters.
Your b parameter is redundant because you set b to a fixed value inside the sigmoid function.  Was that intentional?
Here's a simplified model I fitted to your data without the a parameter.
I didn't flip the y-data and the y-axis of the plot as it is just a source of confusion.  Instead, I put a minus sign inside the sigmoid function.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# 1. Data set: 
x_data = np.array([
    130, 125, 120, 115, 110, 105, 100, 95, 90, 85,
    80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 25
])
y_data = np.array([
    81, 81, 80.5, 79, 77.5, 76, 74.5, 71.5, 68.5, 67, 
    64, 59.5, 55, 48.5, 44, 42.5, 42, 41.5, 41.5, 41, 41, 41
])

# 3. Sigmoid function defined: 
def sigmoid(x, U, k, b):
    a = 1 
    return -(U / (1 + np.exp(-k * (x - 77.5))))**a + b

p0 = [40, -0.1, 81]
x_fit = np.linspace(25, 130, 101)
y_init = sigmoid(x_fit, *p0)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, y_data, p0, maxfev = 10000)
y_est = sigmoid(x_data, *popt)
mse = np.mean((y_data - y_est) ** 2)
print(f"Mean-squared error: {mse:.3f}")

# 4. Sigmoid fit to data:
y_fit = sigmoid(x_fit, *popt)

# 5. Plot data and sigmoid fit:
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, marker='o', linestyle='', color='b', label='Data')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_init, color='r', label='Initial guess')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, color='g', label='Sigmoid Fit')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)')
plt.ylabel('Length (mm)')
plt.title('Sigmoid Fit for Contraction Data')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

Output:
Mean-squared error: 1.679


Additional Result
You can try including the a parameter and see what happens.  I managed to get a good fit with the following 5-parameter model:
def sigmoid(x, U, k, a, b, x0):
    return -((U / (1 + np.exp(-k * (x - x0))))**a) + b

p0 = [40, -0.1, 1.0, 81, 77.5]

Output:
Mean-squared error: 0.227


But use some caution: In this case U was equal to 4.59693084e+19 and a was 85.8494729 !!! This model will probably not behave as expected when extrapolating outside the region of the data you have...
A better strategy is probably to set the a parameter manually as in the previous code and run the optimization a few times with different a values until you get a reasonable solution.

Bill, I am very grateful for the information and help! Generally I was confused with the initial guesses since nearly half have known values from data. I wasn't sure what 'p0' achieved.
I have many datasets per specimen (6 with varied ranges) for which I apply logistic sigmoid fits, then take derivative of function.
I did intentionally place redundant values in the definition because fitting below assumed more parameters to calculate. So, I'd try to match those parameters and try to remove the unnecessary unknown by assigning the value.
I'll try to be more eloquent with my scripts!

That U value is nuts- In my old code for a non-inverted y-value range (the axis), I assigned U a constant matching the maximum y value, against whose constraint the other parameters were extrapolated. When I do that for the above code you amended, it creates a linear line (which tells me its a blown up, small segment of a sigmoid, not fit to the more local data). Sometimes this gets really confusing. Also, I tried to print R^2, now. r_squared = r2_score (y_data, y_fit). [from sklearn.metrics import r2_score]
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [22, 100]

I’m not sure you can use the coefficient of determination (R-squared) for nonlinear regression. I would use the MSE as I showed. What is your aim in calculating it?

Generally the R^2 was just to have a more colloquial representation of fit as a percentage. Anything over 90%. At least visibly from previous datasets I've coded for, it seems to work on these sigmoids. But I have started using the MSE instead as at least, it works, and seems adequate for my needs.
I have created an expansive code, now, plotting multiple datasets together! It looks great. The only issue is that the subplot for the derivatives shows correct plot for only the dataset we worked on, not for the other 5. I'll put that here as an answer to my original post:

I've attached a picture of my success, so far.
The only hiccup (which I think is due to the initial guesses) is the remaining 5 derivative functions which plot as straight lines (same order of magnitude), only the '50m' dataset's plot (and assoc. guesses and calculations) going correctly.
In the 'sigmoid_derivative' definition, I replaced the 'U' parameter with a constant '123' (the maximum value for all datasets (the max. y-value of the 6th dataset 'y_data300m') and the derivative plots all resolved themselves. The plot is: enter image description here
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

# 1. All data sets: 
x_data = np.array([130, 125, 120, 115, 110, 105, 
100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55, 50, 45, 40, 
35, 30, 25])
y_data50 = np.array([81, 81, 80.5, 79, 77.5, 76, 
74.5, 71.5, 68.5, 67, 64, 59.5, 55, 48.5, 44, 42.5, 
42, 41.5, 41.5, 41, 41, 41])
y_data100 = ([91, 91, 91, 91, 89, 87.5, 85, 83.5, 
81, 77, 74.5, 72, 68, 62, 56, 50, 48, 47, 46, 45.5, 
45.5, 45.5]) 
y_data150 = ([99, 99, 99, 99, 97.5, 96, 94, 92, 90, 
87.5, 84, 82, 78, 74, 69, 64, 57, 53, 51, 49, 48, 
48]) 
y_data200 = ([107, 107, 107, 108, 108, 105, 103, 
100, 97.5, 94, 91, 87, 84, 81, 75.5, 69.5, 63, 58, 
53, 52, 51, 50]) 
y_data250 = ([110, 110, 110, 109, 108, 106, 104, 
101.5, 99, 96, 93, 88, 84, 80, 75, 68, 62, 57, 54, 
53, 52, 51]) 
y_data300 = ([123, 123, 122.5, 122, 121.5, 120.5, 
118.5, 116, 113.5, 110, 105.5, 100, 95, 89, 82, 
76.5, 72, 69.5, 67, 66, 65, 65]) 

# 2. Reverse the y-values: 
y_data_reversed50 = np.flip(y_data50)
y_data_reversed100 = np.flip(y_data100)
y_data_reversed150 = np.flip(y_data150)
y_data_reversed200 = np.flip(y_data200)
y_data_reversed250 = np.flip(y_data250)
y_data_reversed300 = np.flip(y_data300)

# 3a. Sigmoid function defined: 
def sigmoid(x, U, k, a, b, x0):
    return -((U / (1 + np.exp(-k * (x - x0))))**a) + 
b
p0_50 = [40, -0.1, 1.0, 125, 77.5] 
p0_100 = [40, -0.1, 1.0, 125, 77.5] 
p0_150 = [40, -0.1, 1.0, 125, 77.5] 
p0_200 = [40, -0.1, 1.0, 125, 77.5] 
p0_250 = [40, -0.1, 1.0, 125, 77.5] 
p0_300 = [40, -0.1, 1.0, 125, 77.5] 

# 3b. Derivative of 'sigmoid' defined: 
def sigmoid_derivative(x, U, k, a, b, x0):
    exponent = -k * (x - x0)
    sigmoid_term = (1 + np.exp(exponent))**(-a - 1)
    return -a * U * k * np.exp(exponent) * 
sigmoid_term 

# 4. Sigmoid fitting operation & mean-squared error 
calculation: 
x_fit = np.linspace(25, 130, 100) 
y_init = sigmoid(x_fit, *p0_50) 
y_init_reversed = np.flip(y_init)

# 4a. Estimated parameters for fitting & mean- 
squared errors: 
# (i.) m(w) = 50m(f) 
popt50, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, 
y_data_reversed50, p0_50, maxfev = 10000) 
y_est50 = sigmoid(x_data, *popt50) 
mse50 = np.mean((y_data_reversed50 - y_est50) ** 2) 
print(f"Mean-squared error: {mse50:.3f}") 
# (ii.) m(w) = 100m(f) 
popt100, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, 
y_data_reversed100, p0_100, maxfev = 10000) 
y_est100 = sigmoid(x_data, *popt100) 
mse100 = np.mean((y_data_reversed100 - y_est100) ** 
2) 
print(f"Mean-squared error: {mse100:.3f}") 
# (iii.) m(w) = 150m(f) 
popt150, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, 
y_data_reversed150, p0_150, maxfev = 10000) 
y_est150 = sigmoid(x_data, *popt150) 
mse150 = np.mean((y_data_reversed150 - y_est150) ** 
2) 
print(f"Mean-squared error: {mse150:.3f}") 
# (iv.) m(w) = 200m(f) 
popt200, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, 
y_data_reversed200, p0_200, maxfev = 10000) 
y_est200 = sigmoid(x_data, *popt200) 
mse200 = np.mean((y_data_reversed200 - y_est200) ** 
2) 
print(f"Mean-squared error: {mse200:.3f}") 
# (v.) m(w) = 250m(f) 
popt250, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, 
y_data_reversed250, p0_250, maxfev = 10000) 
y_est250 = sigmoid(x_data, *popt250) 
mse250 = np.mean((y_data_reversed250 - y_est250) ** 
2) 
print(f"Mean-squared error: {mse250:.3f}") 
# (vi.) m(w) = 300m(f) 
popt300, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, x_data, 
y_data_reversed300, p0_300, maxfev = 10000) 
y_est300 = sigmoid(x_data, *popt300) 
mse300 = np.mean((y_data_reversed300 - y_est300) ** 
2) 
print(f"Mean-squared error: {mse300:.3f}") 

# 4b. Calculation of Sigmoid Fit y-values using the 
estimated parameters per dataset: 
# (i.) [m(w) = 50m(f)]: 
y_fit50 = sigmoid(x_fit, *popt50) 
dy_dx_fit50 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt50) 
# (ii.) [m(w) = 100m(f)]: 
y_fit100 = sigmoid(x_fit, *popt100) 
dy_dx_fit100 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt100) 
# (iii.) [m(w) = 150m(f)]: 
y_fit150 = sigmoid(x_fit, *popt150) 
dy_dx_fit150 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt150) 
# (iv.) [m(w) = 200m(f)]: 
y_fit200 = sigmoid(x_fit, *popt200) 
dy_dx_fit200 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt200) 
# (v.) [m(w) = 250m(f)]: 
y_fit250 = sigmoid(x_fit, *popt250) 
dy_dx_fit250 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt250) 
# (vi.) [m(w) = 300m(f)]: 
y_fit300 = sigmoid(x_fit, *popt300) 
dy_dx_fit300 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt300) 

# 4c. Calculation of Derivative y-values using the 
estimated parameters: 
# (i.) [m(w) = 50m(f)]: 
dy_dx_fit50 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt50) 
# (ii.) [m(w) = 100m(f)]:  
dy_dx_fit100 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt100) 
# (iii.) [m(w) = 150m(f)]: 
dy_dx_fit150 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt150) 
# (iv.) [m(w) = 200m(f)]: 
dy_dx_fit200 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt200) 
# (v.) [m(w) = 250m(f)]: 
dy_dx_fit250 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt250) 
# (vi.) [m(w) = 300m(f)]: 
dy_dx_fit300 = sigmoid_derivative(x_fit, *popt300) 

# 5. Print fitness of fit (R^2 value): 
#r_squared = r2_score(y_data_reversed, y_fit) 
#print("R^2 value:", r_squared) 

# 6. Print the fitted parameters: 
print("Estimated Parameters:", popt50) 
print("Estimated Parameters:", popt100) 
print("Estimated Parameters:", popt150) 
print("Estimated Parameters:", popt200) 
print("Estimated Parameters:", popt250) 
print("Estimated Parameters:", popt300) 

# 7. Plot data, logistic sigmoid function fit, & the 
derivative: 
plt.figure(figsize = (14, 5))

# 7a. Datas' & Sigmoid Fits' Subplot: 
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1) 
#plt.plot(x_data, y_data_reversed50, marker='o', 
linestyle='', color='b', label='Data') 
#plt.plot(x_fit, y_init_reversed, color = 'r', label 
= 'Initial Guess') 
#plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit50, color='g', 
label='Characteristic Sigmoid Fits') 
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit50, '-', color = 'green', 
label=f'm(w) = 50m(f) (RMSE={mse50:.2f})')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit100, '-', color = 'yellow', 
label=f'm(w) = 100m(f) (MSE={mse100:.2f})')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit150, '-', color = 'gold', 
label=f'm(w) = 150m(f) (MSE={mse150:.2f})')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit200, '-', color = 'darkorange', 
label=f'm(w) = 200m(f) (MSE={mse200:.2f})')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit250, '-', color = 'red', 
label=f'm(w) = 250m(f) (MSE={mse250:.2f})')
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit300, '-', color = 'purple', 
label=f'm(w) = 300m(f) (MSE={mse300:.2f})')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)') 
plt.ylabel('Length (mm)') 
plt.title('Sigmoid Fits for Contraction Data') 
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()  # ...Invert y-axis to 
start with highest value at the top
plt.legend() 
plt.grid(True) 

# 7b. Derivatives of the sigmoids' subplot: 
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2) 

plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit50, '--', color = 'green', 
label='Rate for m(w) = 50m(f)')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit100, '--', color = 
'yellow', label='Rate for m(w) = 100m(f)')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit150, '--', color = 'gold', 
label='Rate for m(w) = 150m(f)')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit200, '--', color = 
'darkorange', label='Rate for m(w) = 200m(f)')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit250, '--', color = 'red', 
label='Rate for m(w) = 250m(f)')
plt.plot(x_fit, dy_dx_fit300, '--', color = 
'purple', label='Rate for m(w) = 300m(f)') 
plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)') 
plt.ylabel('(Δ)l/(Δ)T (mm/°C)') 
plt.legend() 
plt.title('Contraction Rates (Derivative of 
Characteristic Sigmoid)') 

plt.show() 

enter image description here

After checking each dataset individually, I see:

all the data can be plotted individually using the same protocol. So, there should be no reason that only 1 derivative curve plots correctly instead of all 6 at once.
Only the '300m' data and the '150m' data have orders of magnitude greater derivative plots (don't get how that's possible, if I'm being honest. And they wouldn't show up, potentially. However, the extremities of those two's derivatives should still have been visible in the "all together" plot of this script, but they weren't.

